# How to Map Columns of Stored Procedure return to POCO class in Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: stored-procedures, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I am using Entity Framework CodeFirst with an existing database. I have an existing stored procedure which returns data from a `Customer_Info` table with 2 columns `Customer_ID, Customer_Name`. I created a class for this entity called `Customer` with 2 Properties `CustomerID, CustomerName`. Now I am trying to get the data via this Stored Procedure. I have my Mapping defined like this in my `OnModelCreating` method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer_Info");
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().
                 Property(x => x.CustomerID).HasColumnName("Customer_ID");
```

This is how i am trying to get data from the stored proc and load the data into the entity.

```
public IList<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
  return context.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("exec GetCustomers @p0","NY")
                                                                       .ToList();
}
```

But it did not work ! It is throwing me an error saying like this

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Customer'. A
>   member of the type, 'CustomerID', does not have a corresponding column
>   in the data reader with the same name.

How do i fix this ? If i read from the table directly, my property mapping works.

Answer (score 0):

Either modify your stored procedure to use something like

```
SELECT Customer_ID AS CustomerID, Customer_Info AS CustomerName ...
```

or modify properties in your `Customer` class to `Customer_ID` and `Customer_Info`. You are using code first and it doesn't support stored procedure mapping. It uses simple built-in mapping where name of property is matched with name of column by its name.

If you want to map stored procedure result set you must give up code first and use EDMX.